# Virtual function in C++

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding

In the below c++ code using virtual functions

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base{
    public:
    virtual void fun(){
        cout << "Base::fun()called \n";
    }

};

class Child : public Base {
    public:
    void fun() {
        cout << "Child::fun() called\n";
    }

    void door(){
        cout << "Child::door() called \n";
    }
};


int main(){

    Base *base_ptr = new Child();
    base_ptr->fun();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I invoke door function using base_ptr? 
This question was asked in an interview.
I was wondering whether it can be possible

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Add `virtual void door()=0;` to you class declaration for `Base`. Or can't you modify Base?

Comment: @drescherjm . No you cant modify Base

Comment: You know, perhaps it was just a trick question to find out how you react when you see OOP and classes used so incorrectly.

Answer (score 6):

*(Assuming that `Base` and `Child` cannot be modified.)*

You can use `static_cast` to convert `base_ptr` to `Child*`.

```
static_cast<Child*>(base_ptr)->door()
```

This is safe as long as you are **sure** that `base_ptr` is actually pointing to a `Child` instance.

---

If you don't know what derived instance type `base_ptr` is pointing to, consider using `dynamic_cast`:

```
if(auto child = dynamic_cast<Child*>(base_ptr))
{
    child->door();
}
```

Unless the compiler manages to aggressively optimize it, `dynamic_cast` has extra runtime overhead compared to `static_cast`.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @FredLarson: there's no reason to use `dynamic_cast` in this particular situation.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: You pointed out the reason yourself in your answer, for `static_cast` to be valid, "you must be sure that `base_ptr` is actually pointing to a `Child` instance".  `dynamic_cast` allows you to determine whether this is so.

Comment: @BenVoigt: which is always true for the situation presented in the question. I updated the answer in order to make it more general, regardless.

Comment: @FredLarson is right, `dynamic_cast` is always the better option simply because it's more resistant to bugs when the code changes and the original assumptions are no longer valid. There are only 2 cases where `static_cast` would be preferred: when there are no virtual functions in the base class, and when you can't afford the overhead of `dynamic_cast` because it's in a tight loop (but you could probably do `dynamic_cast` outside of the loop).

Comment: @MarkRansom: it's not. It's the only option when **you do not know the type** of what your base pointer is referring to, and it's a subpar option **when you do know the type**, because it incurs unnecessary run-time cost.

Comment: @MarkRansom: play around with the example [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/p0LZy4) and see the difference.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo my claim is that the run-time cost is worth the robustness that you gain when making code changes. Most of the time `dynamic_cast` isn't used in an area where it would make a measurable difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I'd argue that you should protect yourself from code changes by tests and assertions, not by introducing unnecessary run-time overhead. If you know the type, use `static_cast` - maybe [wrap it in a safer interface](https://github.com/SuperV1234/vrm_core/blob/master/include/vrm/core/casts/polymorphic.hpp) like I did, which checks correctness in non-release builds.

Comment: Not sure when dynamic_cast will become useful can someone modify the code inside main () and help me on this

Comment: @Zaks instead of initializing `base_ptr` with `new Child`, initialize it with something that chooses between `Child` and `Base` based on user input or a random number.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo so you advocate something like `assert(static_cast<Child*>(base_ptr) == dynamic_cast<Child*>(base_ptr)`? I suppose that's valid, but I would consider it unnecessary clutter when `dynamic_cast` by itself is sufficient 99% of the time. It all depends on your priorities I guess.

Comment: @MarkRansom: it's not clutter if you wrap it in easy-to-use functions like I did. I can't really find a reason to justify the extra cost of `derived_cast` when you *(as the programmer)* know the type of the pointed object. Using `derived_cast` to **`assert`** correctness in non-release builds is more than reasonable, though.

Comment: @MarkRansom Is this correct https://godbolt.org/g/bq27lh . I cant able to print the child door when Base is pointing to itself when doing dynamic_cast .

Comment: @Zaks yes that's correct. You can't call the child function unless you have an actual child object, otherwise you risk undefined behavior. You *don't* want undefined behavior, it might make demons fly from your nostrils.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Base` has no `door()` method, you obviously cannot simply call `base_ptr->door()`.

However, if you know `base_ptr` is a `Child`, you can cast it and then call `door()`

```
Child* child_ptr = static_cast<Child*>(base_ptr);
child_ptr->door();
```